# Какой DOCTYPE лучше?

Tags: html

У меня тегов и атрибутов HTML5 на сайте нет, стоит ли мне в таком случае устанавливать тег `<!DOCTYPE html>` или лучше использовать предыдущую версию тега?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `<!DOCTYPE html>` - хуже не будет, да и лишних заморочек с выбором избежите.

Comment: да, а если тегов хтмл5 нет, так можно добавить, получите небольшой плюс от поисковиков

Comment: @makregistr, интересно, и какой же плюс от поисковиков? Доктайп влияет на валидность html, но на ранжирование ПС никак не влияет ни доктайп, ни, как следствие, валидность.

Comment: плюс относиться к использованию хтмл5 тегов, верстка станет более семантичной, поэтому и плюс